# Python unicode excape underscore and double quotes

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, python-unicode

I have data which represent usernames from different languages. I have carries out proper unicoding process as follows:

```
while attempts < 3 and not success:
    query = ur'''select gu_name from globaluser where gu_name = "{uname}"'''.format(uname=unicode(filerow['user_name'],'utf-8', errors='strict'))
    try:
        self.gdbCursor.execute(query.encode('utf-8'))
        gUser = self.gdbCursor.fetchone()
```

But when it comes to names like this `Name1_"GG"_Name1AnotherName` I ended up getting following error:

`ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'GG" Cooper"\' at line 1')`

How do I properly encode these type of characters?

Update:

Based on the answers provided I did the following:

`\'GG" Cooper"\'` to resolve user name

```
                    while attempts < 3 and not success:
                        #query = ur'''select gu_name from globaluser where gu_name = "{uname}"'''.format(uname=unicode(filerow['user_name'],'utf-8', errors='strict'))
                        uName = unicode(filerow['user_name'], 'utf-8')
                        query = ur'''select gu_name from globaluser where gu_name = "%s"'''
                        try:
                            #self.gdbCursor.execute(query.encode('utf-8'))
                            self.gdbCursor.execute((query % (uName)).encode('utf-8'))
                            gUser = self.gdbCursor.fetchone()
```

But I still get the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near \'GG" Cooper"\' at line 1')
```

Comment: Use parameters inputs instead of string and your names will be properly escaped by the database

Comment: Can you give me a good example or link for one?

Comment: @Vor I updated my code with the answer you provided but didn't really work. I also update the question to show how I did.

Comment: have you tried without `"` around `%s`?

Comment: Yes I ended up getting a operational error when I remove double quotes. `OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'Kelovy' in 'where clause'")`

Comment: actual username is `somename_"GG"_Cooper` it has quotes so need to be escape after I red the link you provided %s should take care of all that...

Answer (score 1):

You should be using parameters inputs as it suggested in:

http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15

Here is an example:

```
sql = "insert into foo values(%s)"
cursor.execute(sql, ('My very %$@*@"""S weird name',))
```